# Reading from binary file in Fortran, how can I do the same thing in Matlab?

Tags: fortran

I'm quite new to this, and I am trying to translate a program from Fortran to Matlab. I've got a question on the READ-function in Fortran. I've got the following definitions:

```
DIMENSION ET2(2),PV(6,12),PNUT(4),T(2),PJD(4),BUF(1500),SS(3),CVAL(400),PVSUN(3,2)
INTEGER LIST(12),IPT(3,13)

CHARACTER*6 TTL(14,3),CNAM(400)                                           
CHARACTER*80 NAMFIL 

COMMON/EPHHDR/CVAL,SS,AU,EMRAT,NUMDE,NCON,IPT                             
COMMON/CHRHDR/CNAM,TTL                                                    
COMMON/STCOMX/KM,BARY,PVSUN
```

And the Read-statements I am trying to understand/translate are the following:

```
READ(NRFILE,REC=1)TTL,CNAM,SS,NCON,AU,EMRAT,((IPT(I,J),I=1,3),J=1,12),NUMDE,(IPT(I,13),I=1,3)

READ(NRFILE,REC=2)CVAL
```

English is not my native language, and I am not quite sure that I've understood the definition of REC. If I e.g. had a file made up of four different integers, would REC=2 indicate that I am starting to read from the second integer?

Second, I am wondering what is happening next. I assume the information from NRFILE is saved in the different variables, TTL, CNAM...? NRFILE is referring to a binary file, but I don't understand how the programme knows which information to store in each variable. I assume the same information isn't stored in both  TTL and CNAM as they have different dimensions?

Does anyone know how this would look in matlab? This far I've only been able to write cval=fread(filID), but than I've ignored the REC statement..

Answer (score 0):

The "REC=n" is for a direct access read.  The records in a direct access file can be read in any order, perhaps out of sequence.   You example shows them being read in sequence, so perhaps this features isn't being used, though you only show the first two reads.   Direct access records are normally fixed length; likely Fortran leaves off the record length information that it normally adds to non-stream unformatted sequential files.

The variables on the I/O list are filled in order that the appear in the list from the bytes in the record.  IPT is filled using an implied do list.  If it isn't sufficiently obvious, you can find questions about that here.

Showing the open statement for the file might be helpful.

Comment: So, REC=1 doesn't mean that only the first record will be read? It means that it will start reading from record one and than read the next one and so on?

Comment: The open statement:
  OPEN(NRFILE,FILE=NAMFIL,ACCESS='DIRECT',FORM='UNFORMATTED',RECL=IRECSZ, STATUS='OLD')

So I guess every record being read consists of the number of bytes eqvivalent with RECL? 

I am a bit uncertain on how to implement this in matlab. I think it is difficult to translate so that the correct records ends up in the correct variables or arrays. How do I know the number of records going in to eg. TTL?

If I am to implement this in matlab, would it than be correct to first read the first n-bytes (size of TTL i suppose?) in to TTL, and than read from there on in to CNAM?

Answer (score 0):

If you are converting fortran to matlab, try out f2matlab. It can often do much of the work for you. Though you will have to check the translation (including these read statements) after f2matlab is done.